# How to execute JavaScript and Django concurrently from a single HTML button?

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-4, django-views

My end-goal is to process my Django view when a button is clicked (to save database info), as well as executing some JavaScript (to display a bootstrap success alert). However, the bug or potential limitation I'm encountering is that I can only do one or the other. I confirmed this to true by simply removing the `onclick="somefunction()"` parameter from the button element. If it's removed, the response is "posted" successfully to my Django view. If it's kept, only the JavaScript function is executed.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```html
{% csrf_token %}
<form method="POST" class="form_group">
  <!-- ...some unrelated bootstrap stuff -->
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel-button-id">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="indicate_if_successful()" id="save-customer-button-id" name="save_customer" value="save_customer">Save customer info</button>
    <!-- The button above is the one having issues -->
  </div>
</form>
```

**Django view**

```py
def add(response):  # This function doesn't get executed if 'onclick' exists

    if response.method == "POST":  
        if response.POST.get("save_customer"):
            pass  # The code I want to execute
```

So in order to execute both the JavaScript function and Django view, what are my options? Should I be doing all of this differently in the first place? I'm open to any alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your javascript `indicate_if_successful()` function should return `true` after it is executed therefore it will run first and after it's completion the form will be submitted also it's better to use `onsubmit` event for form tag here

```
<form method="POST" class="form_group" onsubmit="indicate_if_successful()">

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution seems to work. Emphasis on including `onsubmit` in the `<form>` tag, not the `<button>` tag.

For the sake of others, as Muck's comment below points out-, the alert happens too fast for anyone to see it (simply because Django is obligating me to return an HttpResponse object). This seems to be a separate issue altogether, but it's important to keep in the mind this limitation will require some workaround.

Answer (score 2):

`onclick="somefunction()"` added some lock on your btn. You can use `document.getElementById('save-customer-button-id').addEventListener('click', function(e){...})`, then in function body write code to alert and default behavior(send a form).

But, i think, it will so fast, that user may not see it.